# How to turn off crontab logging on Linux Mint 21

Tags: shell, cron, logs

Every minute I was running my rather silly shell script to ensure my CPU governor is set to powersave. It was an experiment, for the lack of a better word. I forgot about it,... until now when I saw though my logs with:

```sh
$ journalctl --boot --no-pager --no-hostname | grep governor
```

which resulted in 588 lines of log, just since the morning:

```
Nov 20 00:43:01 CRON[4917]: (vlastimil) CMD (/usr/bin/sudo /home/vlastimil/Development/sh/set-cpu-governor-to-powersave >/dev/null 2>&1)
Nov 20 00:43:01 sudo[4918]: vlastimil : PWD=/home/vlastimil ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/home/vlastimil/Development/sh/set-cpu-governor-to-powersave
```

Here's the associated `cron` entry, and please notice the `>/dev/null 2>&1` redirection at the end of that cron:

```sh
* * * * * /usr/bin/sudo /home/vlastimil/Development/sh/set-cpu-governor-to-powersave >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I am kind of confused as to what exactly did I supress with it, but anyway...

How do I supress logging of CRON completely on Linux Mint 21?

Comment: The mention of `>/dev/null 2>&1` is a red herring. That only disposes of the output from the job you ran, not anything from daemons. Can you show an example of the logged lines ?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Sure, will edit soon.

Comment: What's the actual issue with the logging? Space constraints? Do you have log file rotation enabled for that log?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it via crontab, by default it will run as `root`, so you do not need `sudo`, just call the command directly:

```
-* * * * * /home/vlastimil/Development/sh/set-cpu-governor-to-powersave >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The leading `-` means don't log `CRON` and without the `sudo`, it's log will also stop.